# Automated jobs with failover written in PHP

Tags: php, linux, cron

I don't know if this question should have been placed in serverfault.com but I'll try here first.

I have a lot of jobs written in PHP that are currently run as cron jobs. The problem is this method doesn't provide any failover and I would like some more management than I am offered through cron jobs. It is of great importance that the jobs are run at the time they are scheduled. That is why I need failover if something fails. I would love to have something triggering the job at one server and if this never returns or fails to start it tries another server.

How can I manage these jobs and provide some kind of failover? I think the purpose of the jobs have outgrown the cron tab and I need some other engine to manage these jobs. How do people usually run automated jobs that require failover.

Comment: Some answers here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766382/nodejs-job-server-multiple-purpose

Comment: Does sound interesting with the queuing system, but it doesn't solve my problem with failover..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple linux solution you could either use anacron (which doesn't assume that the system is working 24/7 and schedules the required jobs when it is booted again), check http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/05/anacron-examples/ ,  or rcron https://code.google.com/p/rcron/ for a bit more complex stuff.

Comment: Just edited the quest: "It is of great importance that the jobs are run at the time they are scheduled. That is why I need failover if something fails. I would love to have something triggering the job at one server and if this never returns or fails to start it tries another server.". So I don't think anacron would help me to obtain what I need.

Comment: Check rcron from the answer above. It sounds like what you need and it's minimal/easy to setup.

Comment: rcron is the direction I want. But the last update is august 2009 and that's not something I particularly fancy(old software). Furthermore it "only" provides failover on the server level and I am not able to get failover on a lower level ie. something prevents the job from running. The queue sounds interesting since it would contain the queued jobs and the current states (running|failed|ok). Is there something more advanced like rcron?

Comment: rcron with keepalived is the most recommended way for this kind of things from what I read. And even though it was updated a long time ago it's still used by lots of people. If you want something that checks for errors during execution on a lower level you can alter the keepalive script that runs on each node and make it check for successfull execution each time. http://linuxdrops.com/perform-cron-jobs-redundancy-using-rcron-on-centos-rhel-debian-ubuntu-fedora/ Otherwise a solution like http://www.getchef.com/ might have what you want (it has everything inside) but that seems a tad overkill.

Comment: Check this one as well http://nadarei.co/mina/ it might be useful

Comment: Thanks cyph3r! You have given many possibilities. I'm not sure what the end solution will be yet but thanks for your time!